# What is the name of/How do I hide the top bar of the iOS Safari Extension Window?

Tags: javascript, swift, xcode, safari, safari-extension

[Image of the Bar in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMDIZ.png)

For context, I am adding a Safari App Extension to an pre-existing iOS app, which as of writing, Apple still hasn't updated their documentation to say that you can do.

There is a bar when you open an iOS Safari Extension at the top of the extension window that contains the Extension name and a "Done" button.  I, for the life of me, cannot seem to find out the name of that bar, nor how to alter it.  I've seen other iOS extensions both with and without the bar and my best guess is that the ones without it figured out how to hide the bar rather than alter or put content over said bar, but I am unable to find out how to do that either.

What I'd like to know is, what is the name of that bar and how can I hide or cover over that bar since it is ugly and takes up screen real estate that could be better used by a more custom solution?

As for what I was expecting, I was originally expecting some kind of setting I could set in the Manifest file or some option or ability to hide it in the popup related html or js files but since I don't even know the name of the bar, it's hard to get any real info.  The Apple documentation wasn't particularly helpful either, especially since multiple relevant pages don't even say Safari App Extensions (or Safari Extension Apps, whatever) are possible in iOS as of the time of writing this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.